# How to hide user profile fields based on the role of the viewed user?

Tags: users, user-roles, profiles

I want to hide some default fields of the backend user profile page based on the role of the user whose profile is being viewed (by the admin in this case).

I used the simple CSS way to achieve that (here hiding the Bio box):

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_css');

function my_custom_admin_css() {
  echo '<style>

   .user-description-wrap {
       display: none;
    }

   </style>
}
```

but that obviously applies to ALL user roles.

Is there a way to apply this conditionally based on the role of the user whose profile is being viewed?

Comment: Perhaps you start taking a look here [`current_user_can`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)

Answer (score 1):

[`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) checks the current user's specified capability. See [Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

Also, CSS just visually hides the section, but does not remove it from page HTML. The following code checks the capability and completely removes the section.

```
<?php
// For example, 
// any user other than an Admin of single site installation,
// but not Multisite Admin and not SuperAdmin:
if ( ! current_user_can( 'delete_users' ) ) {

    add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_profile_admin_buffer_start' );
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_profile_admin_buffer_end' );

}

function my_remove_about_section( $buffer ) {

    // get section header and everything until the next section
    $about_section = '~<h2>About Yourself</h2>.+?/table>~s';
    // replace it with empty string
    $buffer = preg_replace( $about_section, '', $buffer, 1 );

    return $buffer;
}

function my_profile_admin_buffer_start() {
    ob_start( 'my_remove_about_section' );
}

function my_profile_admin_buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

The whole idea is taken from my old dead pre-WordPress-5 project and is not tested.

Comment: Still works really great!